# Understand Image Upload logic in Flutter via multipart/form-data request?

Tags: flutter, file-upload, upload, multipartform-data, media-type

I'm currently trying to setup a `multipart/form-data` request in a flutter app which uploads a picture taken via the device's camera, using flutters [image picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package.

To take the picture, I simply use:

```
final takenPicture = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.camera
    );

fileForUpload = File(takenPicture.path);
```

I then upload the file according to the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html) using:

```
var uri = Uri.https('example.com', 'create');
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri)
  ..fields['user'] = 'nweiz@google.com'
  ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'pictures[]', fileForUpload.path,
    filename: 'sample.jpg',
      contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpg')));
var response = await request.send();
if (response.statusCode == 200) print('Uploaded!');
```

This now works. The problem I have is that, when you omit the `filename` and the `contentType` argument in the `MultipartFile.fromPath` constructor, the upload occasionally fails with the error message:

`the file exists, but the PHP is_readable() function fails when passed the path to the file.`

Pretty much like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75657042/how-do-i-send-multipart-form-data-in-flutter-and-dart), it only worked once I added a random filename and content type to the request, as shown above; then the error stopped showing up.

I know that the [Multipart](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html) class applies the `application/octet-stream` by default as the content-type of the image; is that maybe the reason? When I `var_dump()` the `$_FILES` variable on the server-side for the times where the above-mentioned upload error occurs, I can see that `tmp_name` is empty, which is probably the reason why the server-side cannot find the upload. When I add the above-mentioned `filename` and `contentType` parameters, the `tmp_name` property of all uploads is always present and the upload seemingly never fails.

Besides the fact that I would really like to understand why this happens, I would also like to know how you should actually set the filename + media type for an image that has been taken via the image picker package. To my understanding, that depends on the device if the image you've selected is `png`, `jpg`, `heic`, etc. Simply extract the mime type via the suffix from the filename, as the upload is then validated on the server-side anyways? Just because the docs do not really explain about the `MediaType` part.

Comment: Make sure in backend there are permission for write a file. most likely its due to backend not have a write permission.

Comment: Can you provide any details about your thoughts?